# Using Regular expressions to match a portion of the string?(python)

Tags: python, regex

What regular expression can i use to match genes(**in bold**) in the gene list string:

GENE_LIST: **F59A7.7**; **T25D3.3**; **F13B12.4**; **cysl-1**; **cysl-2**; **cysl-3**; **cysl-4**; **F01D4.8**

I tried : *GENE_List:((( \w+).(\w+));*)+* but it only captures the last gene

Comment: It appears that the genes are separated by semi-colons. You can use this fact to build a regex to meet your requirements.

Comment: We can help you better if you post a complete python program which you have tried.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given:

```
>>> s="GENE_LIST: F59A7.7; T25D3.3; F13B12.4; cysl-1; cysl-2; cysl-3; cysl-4; F01D4.8"
```

You can use Python string methods to do:

```
>>> s.split(': ')[1].split('; ')
['F59A7.7', 'T25D3.3', 'F13B12.4', 'cysl-1', 'cysl-2', 'cysl-3', 'cysl-4', 'F01D4.8']
```

For a regex:

```
(?<=[:;]\s)([^\s;]+)
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/mZ5dB8/1)

Or, in Python:

```
>>> re.findall(r'(?<=[:;]\s)([^\s;]+)', s)
['F59A7.7', 'T25D3.3', 'F13B12.4', 'cysl-1', 'cysl-2', 'cysl-3', 'cysl-4', 'F01D4.8']
```

Comment: In my case i am searching through a large xml file to find gene information, so i actually need to search for "Gene_list" first and then try to pull each gene out to add it to the list of all genes

Comment: Have you considered using an XML parser such as [ElementTree](https://docs.python.org/2/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html)?

Comment: Yes, i am actually using it, however gene information is not stored as a node of its own, it is listed in the node "notes"  which has a lot of other information(other than the gene names) that i am not currently concerned about

Comment: This is more what i was looking for:  (?<=[(GENE_LIST):;]\s)([^\s;]+)

Comment: @SeanSadykoff: The regex `(?<=[(GENE_LIST):;]\s)([^\s;]+)` is not what you think. With the `[]` around `[(GENE_LIST):;]` you are looking for the individual characters of the string `GENE_LIST` which is functionally no different than the regex `(?<=[:;]\s)([^\s;]+)` in this case. If you want to add the string to the lookback, you would do something like `(?<=(?:^GENE_LIST: )|(?:; ))([^\s;]+)` or just eliminate the lookback and use `(?:(?:^GENE_LIST: )|(?:; ))([^\s;]+)`

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following:

```
\s([^;\s]+)
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/iC8zQ7/2)

- The captured group, `([^;\s]+)`, will contain the desired substrings followed by whitespace (`\s`)

---

```
>>> s = 'GENE_LIST: F59A7.7; T25D3.3; F13B12.4; cysl-1; cysl-2; cysl-3; cysl-4; F01D4.8'
>>> re.findall(r'\s([^;\s]+)', s)
['F59A7.7', 'T25D3.3', 'F13B12.4', 'cysl-1', 'cysl-2', 'cysl-3', 'cysl-4', 'F01D4.8']
```

Comment: this will capture the whitespace in front too, so the first gene capture would be ' F59A7.7'

Comment: @RubenPirotte i am not sure if there are multiple whitespaces before each one anyway updated..

Comment: I'm sorry, I think you misunderstood: the \s captures the whitespace, while we only want the gene behind that whitespace.

Comment: so either a trim should be done, or the regex has to be modified.

Comment: @RubenPirotte Did you check the modified answer?

Comment: Yes, the very first `\s` of the regex `\s([^;\s]+)` means capture a whitespace.

Comment: My bad, the parenthesis seem the have more functionality then I thought.

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATE**

It's in fact much simpler:

```
[^\s;]+
```

however, first use substring to take only the part you need (the genes, without GENELIST )

demo: [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/yW5tU1/1)

Comment: Yes, the last gene is not followed by a semicolon

Comment: is the last gene always preceded by a space?

Answer (score 0):

```
string = "GENE_LIST: F59A7.7; T25D3.3; F13B12.4; cysl-1; cysl-2; cysl-3; cysl-4; F01D4.8"
re.findall(r"([^;\s]+)(?:;|$)", string)
```

The output is:

```
['F59A7.7',
'T25D3.3',
'F13B12.4',
'cysl-1',
'cysl-2',
'cysl-3',
'cysl-4',
'F01D4.8']
```